# Make postfix log to show how sender rewriting happens

Tags: smtp, postfix

I'm using postfix SMTP server and I'm rewriting sender and recipient addresses. From the postfix logs, I can see the recipient address rewriting logs,

```
Sep 12 17:23:32 rewritehost postfix/smtp[1223]: 28A6701362: to=<email@domain.com>, orig_to=<email@domain2.com>, relay=relay.host[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:25, delay=56, delays=51/0/4.5/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Message accepted for delivery)
```

Here, I sent an email to email@domain2.com, but then it is getting a rewrite by postfix and then email is sent to email@domain.com ( basically I understand recipient rewrite happened)

Similarly, I need to enable the logs for sender rewrite. I made the following change in /etc/postfix/master.cf file

```
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup -v
```

and it showed long verbose logs how cleanup daemon does the sender recipient rewrite.But I do not want to enable verbose mode.

Comment: Please move this question to serverfault if this is not the right place to ask.

Answer (score 2):

As quoted by victor from postfix mailing list:

```
You can cause the envelope sender to be logged via the INFO action
of access(5):

    main.cf:
        smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions =
                check_sender_access static:INFO

This will record the original envelope sender before rewriting happens
downstream in cleanup(8).
```

http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/Make-postfix-log-to-show-how-sender-rewriting-happens-td87954.html

Comment: Note: `INFO` was added to `access` in postfix 3.0. In earlier versions, you can use `WARN` instead.

Comment: You can find the INFO output in /var/log/mail.info in the following format:
... info: END-OF-MESSAGE from localhost[127.0.0.1]: ; from=<...> to=<...> proto=ESMTP helo=<...>